# Unintended loop using struct and switch

Tags: c, loops, struct, switch-statement

Trying to write a car rental program which starts out with a menu of options. After picking, the selected option should execute, however, the program is stuck in a loop of menu -> user input -> menu -> user input -> repeat.

I assume it has something to do with the 'while ( choice = true )' in the main function. Nothing I've tried changes it to false, though.
I'm also having trouble getting anything in any of the case statements to execute.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0

void handleSelection (CompanyT *company, int choice);

void printMenu()
{
    printf ("1 Add new car to the inventory.\n");
    printf ("2 Make a reservation.\n");
    printf ("3 Find a reservation using a renter name and print it to the screen.\n");
    printf ("4 Check out a car given a renter name.\n");
    printf ("5 Print all available cars.\n");
    printf ("6 Calclate and print the average number of days rented.\n");
    printf ("7 Exit program.\n");
}
void handleSelection ( CompanyT *company, int choice)
{
    double value;
    switch ( choice) {
            case 1 :
                    value = 0;
                    choice = value;
                    printf ("%s", choice);
                    break; //optional(?)
            case 2 :
                    printf ("2");
                    break;
            case 3 :
                    printf ("3");
                    break;
            case 4 :
                    printf ("4");
                    break;
            case 5 :
                    printf ("5");
                    break;
            case 6 :
                    printf ("6");
                    break;
            case 7 :
                    choice = 0;
                    printf ("7");
                    break;

    default : printf ("Invalid entry.");
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

int main ( void )
{
    CompanyT myCompany;
    int     choice;
    //add pre-defined list of cars to the list
    createInventory ( &myCompany );

    while ( choice = true ) {
            printMenu();
printf ("Choose option: ");
  scanf ("%d", &choice);  
    handleSelection;
    };
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

full program, if you're trying to compile it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0

typedef short int BoolT; //random true/false value

typedef struct {  //struct that records a car's information
    int carId;
    char make[20];
    char model[20];
    int numDoors;
    double rate;
    //complete this
} CarT;

typedef struct {  //struct that identifies a possible renter
    char renterName[20];
    //complete this
} RentalT;

typedef struct {  //struct that makes a reservation for a predetermined renter
    char renterName[20];
    //complete this
} ReservT;

typedef struct {  //struct that tracks the number of cars and rentals
    CarT allCars[20];
    RentalT allRentals[20];
    //complete this
} CompanyT;

/**
 * Prints a menu to the screen.
 */
void printMenu();

/**
* Creates the intial inventory of cars the company owns.
* company - the company whose inventory will be initialized
*/
void createInventory ( CompanyT *company );

/**
 * Adds new car to the inventory.
 *
 * company  the company that will add a new res
 */
void addNewCar ( CompanyT *company );

/**
 * Creates a new reservation prompting the user for information
 *
* company - the company that will add a new reservation
*/
void makeReservation ( CompanyT *company );

/**
 * Finds a reservation prompting the user for a rental name to locate the res record.
 *
 * company - the company whose reservations will be searched
 */
int findReservation ( CompanyT *company );

void handleSelection (CompanyT *company, int choice);



void printMenu()
{
    printf ("1 Add new car to the inventory.\n");
    printf ("2 Make a reservation.\n");
    printf ("3 Find a reservation using a renter name and print it to the screen.\n");
    printf ("4 Check out a car given a renter name.\n");
    printf ("5 Print all available cars.\n");
    printf ("6 Calclate and print the average number of days rented.\n");
    printf ("7 Exit program.\n");
}

void handleSelection ( CompanyT *company, int choice)
{
    double value;

    switch ( choice ) {
            case 1 :
                    choice = 0;
                    printf ("%s", choice);
                    break; //optional(?)
            case 2 :
                    printf ("2");
                    break;
            case 3 :
                    printf ("3");
                    break;
            case 4 :
                    printf ("4");
                    break;
            case 5 :
                    printf ("5");
                    break;
            case 6 :
                    printf ("6");
                    break;
            case 7 :
                    choice = 0;
                    printf ("7");
                    break;

    default : printf ("Invalid entry.");

    }
    printf ("\n");
}

int main ( void )
{
    CompanyT myCompany;
    int     choice;

    //add pre-defined list of cars to the list
    createInventory ( &myCompany );

    while ( choice  = true ) {
            printMenu();
printf ("Choose option: ");
  scanf ("%d", &choice);  
    handleSelection;
    };


    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
void createInventory ( CompanyT *company )
{
    (*company).allCars[0].carId = 1234;
    strcpy ((*company).allCars[0].make, "Vw");
    strcpy ((*company).allCars[0].model, "Golf");
    (*company).allCars[0].numDoors = 2;
    (*company).allCars[0].rate = 66.0f;

    //complete this
}

void addNewCar ( CompanyT *company )
{
    //complete this
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `while ( choice  = true )` statement.

`choice = true` is an assignment which will make choice to be true. The result will be the the result of the assignment, So you get `while(true)`, which is an infinite loop.

What you really need in this situation is a do while loop, as this will run at least once and then examine the value of `choice`

```
do {
    printMenu();
    printf ("Choose option: ");
   scanf ("%d", &choice);  
   handleSelection;
} while ( choice == true );
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` is the assignment operator. `==` is the equality check.

```
while ( choice = true ) {
```

should be

```
while (choice == true) {
```

or better yet

```
while(choice) {
```

Also note that you use `choice` without giving it any value. In C this means it can have any value (whatever happens to be at that memory location) - i.e. this is undefined behavior.

Comment: I tried both
     while (choice == true)
and
     while (choice)
but my menu failed to run at all in either instance?

Comment: @Annalynn You should add a `choice = true` stetement above the while loop to run it the first time. Or better yet, you should use a do... while loop.